# Re size different images without distortion

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

All the images have one thing in common; they are all 300 or 600 pixels wide. But the heights vary from around 300-900 pixels. Now I need a small group of the images which will be used to suggest other images for the user. These will only be around 100x200 pixels(might change). My previous attempt has made the images shrink into the 100x200 aspect ratio. I need it to overlap, but the excess is hidden.

Comment: If you want the excess to be hidden apply CSS rule: overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this http://dabblet.com/gist/2769112

The CSS you will need is simply

```
.img-container {
    width: 200px; /* whatever set width */
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block; /* or you could float them */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the images in a wrapping element, such as a DIV, with a defined height and width and use `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: I cannot define the height as each image is different? Or do you mean when i echo them out i get the height then set it?

Comment: You are defining the size of the WRAPPER, not the images. I suggest you set a common height for the images, in the IMG tag, and allow them to overflow the container if they are wider than the container.